# Visual studio code alignment

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

How can i align my css to look like this in visual studio code ?

```
   background : $pale
   color      : $black
   font-family: $font-stack
   font-size  : $font-size
```

is there is any plugin to do this automatically instead of selecting the text every time ?

Comment: You can change some options for `CSS` under `Tools`->`Options`->`Text Editor`->`CSS`. This won't really help with spacing, and you'll have to do that yourself manually. Even in languages like `C#` and `C++` you have to manually align things of this nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [Better Align](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align) will do this